# MongoDB:Invalid BSONObj size when syncing

Tags: mongodb, synchronization

i have a 3-server replset, and today i found some strange messages in mongodb.log which never appeared before:

> Fri Feb 20 10:17:12 [rsSync] Assertion: 10334:Invalid BSONObj size:
>   -286331154 (0xEEEEEEEE) first element: _id: ObjectId('54d96ab42d46d5c91edf6651') 0x588cb2 0x5077a1 0x8ba7f8
>   0x94572e 0x949e45 0x94c395 0x830411 0x82100b 0x821d85 0x8231d8
>   0x82439a 0x824820 0xaa4560 0x3ecf40683d 0x3ececd4f8d
>   /opt/mongo/bin/mongod(_ZN5mongo11msgassertedEiPKc+0x112) [0x588cb2] 
>   /opt/mongo/bin/mongod(_ZNK5mongo7BSONObj14_assertInvalidEv+0x471)
>   [0x5077a1]  /opt/mongo/bin/mongod(_ZNK5mongo7DiskLoc3objEv+0xa8)
>   [0x8ba7f8]  /opt/mongo/bin/mongod [0x94572e] 
>   /opt/mongo/bin/mongod(_ZN5mongo14_updateObjectsEbPKcRKNS_7BSONObjES2_bbbRNS_7OpDebugEPNS_11RemoveSaverE+0x2b85)
>   [0x949e45] 
>   /opt/mongo/bin/mongod(_ZN5mongo13updateObjectsEPKcRKNS_7BSONObjES2_bbbRNS_7OpDebugE+0x125)
>   [0x94c395] 
>   /opt/mongo/bin/mongod(_ZN5mongo21applyOperation_inlockERKNS_7BSONObjEb+0xb81)
>   [0x830411] 
>   /opt/mongo/bin/mongod(_ZN5mongo11ReplSetImpl9syncApplyERKNS_7BSONObjE+0x1fb)
>   [0x82100b] 
>   /opt/mongo/bin/mongod(_ZN5mongo11ReplSetImpl8syncTailEv+0xce5)
>   [0x821d85] 
>   /opt/mongo/bin/mongod(_ZN5mongo11ReplSetImpl11_syncThreadEv+0xc8)
>   [0x8231d8] 
>   /opt/mongo/bin/mongod(_ZN5mongo11ReplSetImpl10syncThreadEv+0x4a)
>   [0x82439a]  /opt/mongo/bin/mongod(_ZN5mongo15startSyncThreadEv+0xa0)
>   [0x824820]  /opt/mongo/bin/mongod(thread_proxy+0x80) [0xaa4560] 
>   /lib64/libpthread.so.0 [0x3ecf40683d]  /lib64/libc.so.6(clone+0x6d)
>   [0x3ececd4f8d] Fri Feb 20 10:17:12 [rsSync] replSet syncTail: 10334
>   Invalid BSONObj size: -286331154 (0xEEEEEEEE) first element: _id:
>   ObjectId('54d96ab42d46d5c91edf6651'), syncing: { ts: Timestamp
>   1424343003000|76, h: -3506864587493877515, v: 2, op: "u", ns:
>   "gingko.docindex", o2: { _id: ObjectId('54c220444a9d689b8ca0bb59') },
>   o: { $set: { l: 0 } } }

when i found these, mongo version is 1.4.9, then i update to 2.6.7, and restart the replset. after that, the error keep happening, and mongod process exit.

> 2015-02-20T11:05:11.962+0800 [repl writer worker 1] Assertion:
>   10334:BSONObj size: -286331154 (0xEEEEEEEE) is invalid. Size must be
>   between 0 and 16793600(16MB) First element: _id:
>   ObjectId('54d96ab42d46d5c91edf6651') 2015-02-20T11:05:11.972+0800
>   [repl writer worker 1] gingko.docindex 0x11fd1b1 0x119efa9 0x1183b56
>   0x11840ac 0x77402b 0xf02038 0xd34f4d 0xc4d1e9 0xc58f46 0xc47be7
>   0xe5684b 0xeba03e 0xeba950 0x119284e 0x1241b49 0x3ecf40683d
>   0x3ececd4f8d  mongod(_ZN5mongo15printStackTraceERSo+0x21) [0x11fd1b1] 
>   mongod(_ZN5mongo10logContextEPKc+0x159) [0x119efa9] 
>   mongod(_ZN5mongo11msgassertedEiPKc+0xe6) [0x1183b56]  mongod
>   [0x11840ac]  mongod(_ZNK5mongo7BSONObj14_assertInvalidEv+0x41b)
>   [0x77402b]  mongod(_ZNK5mongo7DiskLoc3objEv+0x68) [0xf02038] 
>   mongod(_ZN5mongo12IDHackRunner7getNextEPNS_7BSONObjEPNS_7DiskLocE+0x33d)
>   [0xd34f4d] 
>   mongod(_ZN5mongo6updateERKNS_13UpdateRequestEPNS_7OpDebugEPNS_12UpdateDriverEPNS_14CanonicalQueryE+0x9a9)
>   [0xc4d1e9]  mongod(_ZN5mongo14UpdateExecutor7executeEv+0x66)
>   [0xc58f46] 
>   mongod(_ZN5mongo6updateERKNS_13UpdateRequestEPNS_7OpDebugE+0x27)
>   [0xc47be7] 
>   mongod(_ZN5mongo21applyOperation_inlockERKNS_7BSONObjEbb+0x199b)
>   [0xe5684b] 
>   mongod(_ZN5mongo7replset8SyncTail9syncApplyERKNS_7BSONObjEb+0x4fe)
>   [0xeba03e] 
>   mongod(_ZN5mongo7replset14multiSyncApplyERKSt6vectorINS_7BSONObjESaIS2_EEPNS0_8SyncTailE+0x50)
>   [0xeba950]  mongod(_ZN5mongo10threadpool6Worker4loopEv+0x19e)
>   [0x119284e]  mongod [0x1241b49]  /lib64/libpthread.so.0 [0x3ecf40683d]
>   /lib64/libc.so.6(clone+0x6d) [0x3ececd4f8d]
>   2015-02-20T11:05:11.972+0800 [repl writer worker 1] ERROR: writer
>   worker caught exception:  :: caused by :: 10334 BSONObj size:
>   -286331154 (0xEEEEEEEE) is invalid. Size must be between 0 and 16793600(16MB) First element: _id:
>   ObjectId('54d96ab42d46d5c91edf6651') on: { ts: Timestamp
>   1424343003000|76, h: -3506864587493877515, v: 2, op: "u", ns:
>   "gingko.docindex", o2: { _id: ObjectId('54c220444a9d689b8ca0bb59') },
>   o: { $set: { l: 0 } } } 2015-02-20T11:05:11.972+0800 [repl writer
>   worker 1] Fatal Assertion 16360 2015-02-20T11:05:11.972+0800 [repl
>   writer worker 1]
>   ***aborting after fassert() failure

the table "gingko.docindex" have 120 million records, read heavy, write not so heavy. by the way, another slave is all right when syncing, and the whole replset was built up 3 years ago.

i search a lot for this, but didn't get any similar problem, any one can give any advise? thanks a lot!

lvzheng

Comment: Wow. 1.4.9 is ancient. There are a number of replication bugs that caused problems like this and you should absolutely upgrade to a recent version like 2.4 or 2.6. You should be able to fix the problem by stepping down the primary and resyncing from a secondary. If the problem persists after you upgrade and resync, I would post a new question with the logs.

Comment: i'm so sorry, it's 2.4.9.